# How to get the value of column D in the current row?

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a simple spreadsheet such as this:

```
A  B      C   D
1  Hello  30  60
2  World  45  90
...
```

…where I want column D to simply be column C*2, how could I do that? Obviously, I could manually set the contents of each row's D column to be `=C1 *2`, `=C2 *2`, and so on, but if I have hundreds of rows, it'd be easier to have something along the lines of `=C$ROW *2` — is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy/paste the formula down, the spreadsheet app will automatically update indices appropriately.  This is the standard way to do this kind of operation in spreadsheet applications; if you want to force a particular row/col ref to not update, prepend a $:

```
=sum($A$1:$A$9999)  // this reference will never change
=$A1                // this will always reference column A but will follow row changes
```